# Adding ticks to 2 axes of a persp plot

Tags: r, plot, 3d, axes

I would like to add numeric axes to my persp plot with the following code

```
persp(F1, phi=30, theta=120, xlab="x", ylab="y", zlab="z", axes=T, ticktype="detailed")
```

However, I do not want the ticks on the z axis.

How can I remove these ticks whilst preserving the ticks/values on the x & y axes?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: [This link](http://entrenchant.blogspot.com/2014/03/custom-tick-labels-in-r-perspective.html) describes one way to accomplish this.

Comment: Please always supply [a reproducible example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). We have no way of knowing what `F1` is.

Comment: The identity of 'F1' is not important to this, the question is about graphical parameters.